# rospy subscribing to topic, how can i save a variable?

Tags: ros, rospy, subscribe, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm fairly new to programming in python and ROS, but my problem is as follows:
I am using a robot gripper, and for control purposes i need to read the status of the gripper and save it to a variable, so I can use if in control sequences. I am getting the status of the gripper by subscribing to a topic.

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('robotiq_s_model_control')
import rospy
from robotiq_s_model_control.msg import _SModel_robot_input  as inputMsg
from robotiq_s_model_control.msg import _SModel_robot_output  as outputMsg

def Callback(data):
    myvar = data
    
rospy.init_node('rq3_proxy')

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.Subscriber("SModelRobotInput", inputMsg.SModel_robot_input, Callback)
    rospy.sleep(1)
    
    print "myvar is: " + myvar

    if myvar == 1:
         #do something"
    elif myvar == 0:
         #do something else
    else :
         #error
```

So my question is: how can I make use of the myvar variable outside the Callback function?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide, and if you need additional info, just ask for it.

/Morten

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92166/rospy-subscribing-to-topic,-how-can-i-save-a-variable?/) by [mortenpj](https://answers.ros.org/users/7376/mortenpj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('robotiq_s_model_control')
import rospy
from robotiq_s_model_control.msg import _SModel_robot_input  as inputMsg
from robotiq_s_model_control.msg import _SModel_robot_output  as outputMsg

myvar = None

def Callback(data):
    global myvar
    myvar = data

rospy.init_node('rq3_proxy')

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.Subscriber("SModelRobotInput", inputMsg.SModel_robot_input, Callback)
    rospy.sleep(1)

   print "myvar is: " + myvar

   if myvar == 1:
         #do something"
    elif myvar == 0:
         #do something else
    else :
         #error
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mortenpj](https://answers.ros.org/users/7376/mortenpj/) on 2013-10-17**:
Thanks! It's is exactly what I needed!
Sorry for my poor python skills! :)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-18**:
You're welcome. If it works, mark the answer as correct, please.